# ReactJS Accessing Nested Objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm making a call to https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/global/, to display each property,  I can access `active_cryptocurrencies` and `active_markets` but not `total_market_cap` or `total_volume_24h`. It says they're `undefined`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { ScaleLoader } from "halogenium";

import styleConstants from "../misc/style_constants.js";

import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { fetchMarketOverviewData } from "../actions/api";

const Wrapper = styled.section`
  color: ${styleConstants.get("Light")};
  margin: 20px 0;
`;

const Table = styled.table`
  width: 100%;
`;

const TableData = styled.td`
  &:nth-child(even) {
    text-align: right;
  }
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: #234558 solid 0.1px;
`;

const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
  style: "currency",
  currency: "USD",
  minimumFractionDigits: 0
});

export class Overview extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: true
  };

  static propTypes = {
    overview: PropTypes.object
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    overview: {}
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchOverviewData;
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.overview === undefined) return null;
    console.log("next Props", nextProps);
    return {
      isLoading: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <ScaleLoader
          color={styleConstants.get("Light")}
          size="16px"
          margin="4px"
        />
      );
    } else {
      let {
        active_cryptocurrencies,
        active_markets,
        quotes
      } = this.props.overview;
      console.log("Overview Render() : ", this.props.overview);
      return (
        <Wrapper>
          <Table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <TableData>Total Market Cap</TableData>
                <TableData>{formatter.format()}</TableData>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <TableData>Total 24 Volume</TableData>
                <TableData>{formatter.format(4)}</TableData>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <TableData>Active Markets</TableData>
                <TableData>{active_markets}</TableData>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <TableData>Active Currencies</TableData>
                <TableData>{active_cryptocurrencies}</TableData>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        </Wrapper>
      );
    }
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const { data } = state.api.marketOverviewData;
  return {
    overview: data
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  fetch: dispatch(fetchMarketOverviewData())
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Overview);
```

Here is the [codingsandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/qv5vl50j1w) any insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: There is something not right in your componentDidMount. I think you should be calling a function? But you are not. Additionally your mapDispatchToProps leads me to believe that within componentDidMount you want to call this.props.fetch()

Comment: Additionally, the data is undefined because it doesn't exist yet. Using componentDidMount, there will be an initial render, and since the fetch has not completed that data will be undefined. You either need to have some sort of mechanism to stop rendering until you get the data, ie loader, or have default values for the data that you need to access, so it can use that until the fetch is complete

Comment: Please let me know if any of that is not clear. These are surface observations from a quick glance at the code, which is why I didn't write an answer.

Comment: @Matthew if you write an answer, I will accept it. The issue is what you said, I meant to call `fetch` but I did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to call `this.props.fetch()` instead of `this.props.fetchOverviewData;`

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetch();
}
```

Additional food for thought:
Using componentDidMount, there will be an initial render, and since the fetch has not completed that data will be undefined. You either need to have some sort of mechanism to stop rendering until you get the data, ie loader, or have default values for the data that you need to access, so it can use that until the fetch is complete